# How to rewrite my append line in Python 3 code?

Tags: python, string

My code

```
token = open('out.txt','r')

linestoken=token.readlines()
tokens_column_number = 1
r=[]
for x in linestoken:
    r.append(x.split()[tokens_column_number])
token.close()

print (r)
```

**Output**

`'"tick2/tick_calculated_2_2020-05-27T11-59-06.json.gz",'`

**Desired output**

```
"tick2/tick_calculated_2_2020-05-27T11-59-06.json.gz"
```

How to get rid of `''` and `,` ?

Comment: `print(''.join(r))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be nice to see your input data. I have created an input file which is similar than yours (I hope).

**My test file content:**

```
example1 "tick2/tick_calculated_2_2020-05-27T11-59-06.json.gz", aaaa
example2 "tick2/tick_calculated_2_2020-05-27T11-59-07.json.gz", bbbb
```

You should replace the `"`, ',' characters.

You can do it with `replace` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace):

```
r.append(x.split()[tokens_column_number].replace('"', "").replace(",", ""))
```

You can do it with `strip` (https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip):

```
r.append(x.split()[tokens_column_number].strip('",'))
```

You can do it with `re.sub` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
import re

...
...
for x in linestoken:
    x = re.sub('[",]', "", x.split()[tokens_column_number])
    r.append(x)
...
...
```

**Output in both cases:**

```
>>> python3 test.py
['tick2/tick_calculated_2_2020-05-27T11-59-06.json.gz', 'tick2/tick_calculated_2_2020-05-27T11-59-07.json.gz']
```

---

As you can see above the output (`r`) is a `list` type but if you want to get the result as a string, you should use the `join` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join).

**Output with `print(",".join(r))`:**

```
>>> python3 test.py
tick2/tick_calculated_2_2020-05-27T11-59-06.json.gz,tick2/tick_calculated_2_2020-05-27T11-59-07.json.gz
```

**Output with `print("\n".join(r))`:**

```
>>> python3 test.py
tick2/tick_calculated_2_2020-05-27T11-59-06.json.gz
tick2/tick_calculated_2_2020-05-27T11-59-07.json.gz
```